# Changing Icon for Main Menu in MATE-Panel with dconf-editor

Tags: icons, mate

I am aware that this question was already posed in a similar way. I then got a perfect answer to do it via dconf-editor -> org -> mate -> panel -> objects. INstalling now MATE with the dame configuration (Ubuntu 22.04.1.LTS, Kernel 5.15-0-52, MateVersion 1.26, and dconfedito4 3.38.3) on a laptop, I have less choices in the given menu: While on the older computer I could eg. change the icon,

[image: Version on Destop]

on the newly installed version I only habe a much more limited choice

[image: Version on Laptop]

I simply do not understand the reason - maybe somebdoy can help...

B.

Comment: The new version has changed some settings. You can submit a bug report if you like. https://ubuntu.com/blog/the-keys-to-successful-bug-reporting

Comment: I understand, but I use the same versionon both computers with exactly the same settings...